# Loading image from picture library to image source

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am capturing an image . Project places the image in picture library that is `C:\...\Pictures\PreviewFrame.jpg`.
I have an image tag

```
<Image Name="ClinicImage"></Image>
```

Now i want to load that `PreviewFrame.jpg` in this tag.
I tried this

```
ClinicImage.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
```

where
path is a string variable containing image path.

But it is not getting loaded. How should i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some retrictions about what the universal applications can access.
You need first to be sure that the picture library capability is properly added in your application manifest.

Then, you can open the image using [GetFileFromPathAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx) and provide the stream to the BitmapSource using [SetSourceAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync.aspx)

```
 var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("c:\\users\\me\\images\\a.png");
var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
await imageSource.SetSourceAsync(stream);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your slashes are set correctly. If I remember correctly, you need to work with double backslash instead of single.

Comment: i am not changing hard coding the path, i get path as a string. I am using it while creating bitmap image.